# How to pass Maven settings via environment vars

Tags: maven

In our setting.xml file we have the following:

```
<servers>
    <server>
      <id>deploymentRepo</id>
      <username>repouser</username>
      <password>repopwd</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

Would it be possible to pass those settings (or their equivalent) via environmental variables instead of the settings.xml?

Comment: Security concerns.  We do not want those values in a file.

Comment: if you pass the passwords via environment variables they will appear in the process list. Maven has some support to encrypt passwords: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html

Comment: @wemu, thanks for the feedback.  we are looking into that also.

Comment: Exactly the opposite, cause environment variables are visible go the way as @wemu suggested.

Comment: @khmarbaise how exactly can I see the env vars of another process?  I tested this out and didn't see them.

Comment: When building on a CI SaaS, using "private variables" to pass secret tokens to builds through the environment is the BKM and considered secure. Editing a "user home file" is considered insecure.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in two ways:

- passing properties in the command line, using variables. For example, you can use in your `settings.xml` something like this:

```xml
<servers>
    <server>
      <id>deploymentRepo</id>
      <username>${server.username}</username>
      <password>${server.password}</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

And in the command line, pass these variables in this way:

```
mvn clean package -Dserver.username=yourusername -Dserver.password=yourpassword
```

Please note that passing password as command-line options is a [security issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/78736/130487) and therefore prefer the second option.

- exporting environments properties. For example, if you export (in Linux, something like `export SERVER_USERNAME=yourusername`) `SERVER_USERNAME` and `SERVER_PASSWORD` variables, you can use like this:

```xml
<servers>
    <server>
      <id>deploymentRepo</id>
      <username>${env.SERVER_USERNAME}</username>
      <password>${env.SERVER_PASSWORD}</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

For more information about properties, see the [reference](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass values from command line

> mvn -Dvar=someValue -Dtest.username=xyz install

In the POM file, you can refer to system variables (specified on the command line, or in the pom) as ${var}, and environment variables as ${env.myVariable} i.e,${test.username}

You can also refer to the sure-fire plugin [doc](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the URL including the credentials like

`mvn deploy -DaltReleaseDeploymentRepository=myrepo::https://user:pass@server/repo`

see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html

Answer (score 0):

The world has changed significantly in the past almost a decade since this was first written, so as is often the case with security it can help to start with a bit of [threat modelling](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Threat_Modeling_Cheat_Sheet.html). Perhaps one will choose to accept the risk, but perhaps one will not if that could have some [extremely serious consequences](https://cyberinsureone.com/laws-penalties/).

If it's [one's local machine and an attacker's got in, one has got bigger problems](https://www.quora.com/What-should-I-do-when-a-hacker-has-control-of-my-computer).

More likely if one is reading this today, one is in a cloud security context. Then for example [TrendMicro considers environment variables](https://www.trendmicro.com/en_au/research/22/h/analyzing-hidden-danger-of-environment-variables-for-keeping-secrets.html) themselves to be full of hidden dangers and thus a security issue, and instead to use a vault (not to be confused with JackRabbit FileVault), for example see [this StackExchange comparison of environment variables with Hashicorp Vault](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/159772/what-security-advantages-does-hashicorp-vault-have-over-storing-secrets-passwor/168869#168869), to reduce any identified risks to a minimum and make it harder for cybercriminals.