# How to use Jenkins credentials when running `mvn deploy`?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, maven-3

I have a Maven project and want to build it using `mvn clean deploy` so that the built artifact is deployed into a Nexus repository.

The access data (username and password) for that repository are stored in Jenkins credentials.

I want to call `mvn deploy` in Jenkins so that the credentials for that Nexus repository are read from Jenkins (not hardcoded in `settings.xml`).

How can I do it, if I cannot access `settings.xml` on the Jenkins server?

**Update 1:**

I created an entry in "Config File Management" (`JENKINS_URL/configfiles/index`) with following data:

Type: `Maven settings.xml`

Replace All: Yes

Server ID: `myServer`

Credentials: `Credentials for the Nexus repository`

Content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>myServer</id>
      <username>foo</username>
      <password>bar</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

[image: Edit configuration file]

`myServer` is also used in the `pom.xml` of the artifact I want to build:

```
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>myServer</id>
            <url>http://nexus.mycompany.com</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

In the configuration of the job, I include those settings as shown below. `Nexus settings.xml` is the configuration from "Config File Management".

[image: Jenkins build configuration]

But it does not work -- I get "Forbidden" error when the build attempts to deploy artifacts to Nexus.

**Update 2:** When I run `mvn -X deploy` locally with the same credentials as in Jenkins (stored in my local `settings.xml`), I see following output:

```
[DEBUG] Failed to decrypt password for server XXX release repository: org.sonatype.plexus.components.sec.dispatcher.SecDispatcherException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/.m2/settings-security.xml (No such file or directory)
org.sonatype.plexus.components.sec.dispatcher.SecDispatcherException: org.sonatype.plexus.components.sec.dispatcher.SecDispatcherException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/.m2/settings-security.xml (No such file or directory)
    at org.sonatype.plexus.components.sec.dispatcher.DefaultSecDispatcher.decrypt(DefaultSecDispatcher.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.settings.crypto.DefaultSettingsDecrypter.decrypt(DefaultSettingsDecrypter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.settings.crypto.DefaultSettingsDecrypter.decrypt(DefaultSettingsDecrypter.java:63)
    at org.apache.maven.internal.aether.DefaultRepositorySystemSessionFactory.newRepositorySession(DefaultRepositorySystemSessionFactory.java:165)
```

However, the password in `settings.xml` is not encrypted at all:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                  https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
<localRepository/>
<interactiveMode/>
<offline/>
<pluginGroups/>
<servers>
  <server>
    <id>NEXUS_REPOSITORY_SNAPSHOTS</id>
    <username>user</username>
    <password>password</password>
  </server>
</servers>
<mirrors/>
<proxies/>
<profiles/>
<activeProfiles/>
</settings>
```

I found a report about similar error [here](https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven/issues/206).

Comment: Do you want to use credentials for a repository in pom.xml ? If that is the case, you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333577/adding-maven-nexus-repo-to-my-pom-xml

Comment: @Sambit No, I don't. The credentials are stored in Jenkins. There is a menu item "Credentials" in Jenkins configuration page.

Comment: You can check this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57420331/pass-credentials-to-maven-from-jenkins

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Jenkins **config-file-provider** plugin ( link: https://plugins.jenkins.io/config-file-provider/ ) to create one or several Maven settings.xml files.

> **NOTE:** Really this helps also if you need differents settings.xml for
>   different projects.

Then on the maven deploy step of your Jenkins project you can select to point to one of the settings.xml files defined ( instead of pointing to the general Jenkins server /.m2/settings.xml )

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I feel that I'm doing something similar (correct me if I'm wrong) -- see update 1.

Comment: You said on your update that you got a "Forbidden" error when the build attempts to deploy artifacts to Nexus. Can you share the complete error message?

Comment: Here is the error message: `Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project PROJECT_NAME: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact PROJECT_NAME:jar:0.0.8 from/to NEXUS_REPOSITORY_SNAPSHOTS (http://NEXUS_URL/repository/maven-snapshots): Access denied to: http://NEXUS_URL/repository/maven-snapshots/PROJECT_NAME/0.0.8/PROJECT_NAME-0.0.8.jar, ReasonPhrase: Forbidden. -> [Help 1]`

Comment: You shoud avoid to define servers on **content**. Just use **server credentials** to define each server and be sure that credentials you select are correct. Moreover be sure the jenkins server is able to contact the nexus server and also that all variables are evaluated correctly ( e.g. NEXUS_URL )

Comment: same issue. i can do the same if i write a jenkinsfile but not by adding this file in the build step of jenkins