# How to restrict exposing project settings file to all in mavenExecute step of cloud-s4-sdk pipeline?

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

We are working on the s4sdk pipeline implementation for delivery of SAP CloudFoundry applications (spring-boot micro-services) using the SAP Cloud SDK for Java.

We have multiple developers working on multiple micro-services but all these micro-services are having some common dependencies. 
We want to control the versions for all the common dependencies from a central location. 
For this we have created a Maven BOM (Bill of Materials) dependency and added it as the parent in pom.xml of all the micro-services.
The aforementioned BOM is housed in Nexus repository and all pom.xmls (of the micro-services) can access the parent using the repository tag like below.

```
   <repository> 
          <id>my-repo</id> 
          <name>nexus-repo</name> 
          <url>http://some/url</url> 
   </repository> `
```

The credentials for the above nexus repository are placed in the **settings.xml** file.

We want to run the above model in the cloud-s4-sdk pipeline. Although it works fine, the problem is that we need to expose the nexus repo access credentials in the settings.xml file.

Per documentation in https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-pipeline/blob/master/configuration.md#mavenexecute, the settings.xml for maven builds needs to be placed relative to the 
project root. This is a security concern for us as the project repository is in GitHub and as such projectSettingsFile can be accessed by the developers.

We don't want these credentials to be exposed to the developers. It should be limited to only the admin team. 
Is there a way we can achieve this using the cloud-s4-sdk pipeline?

Although nexus facilitates user token for maven settings.xml, but that does not work here as GUI login is still possible using the token values.

Answer (score 3):

I think you could consider the following options:

**Allow anonymous read access for artifacts**
The developers anyway need a way to build the artifacts locally. How could developers build your service without having access to a dependency. Allowing read access would also enable them to do that.

**Commit credentials to git but make git repository private**
If you don't want to allow all employees (I guess the only employees have access to your nexus), you can commit the credentials together with the settings.xml but make the repository private to not share these details.

**Inject credentials as environment variable**

You can inject the credentials as environment variable to your settings xml file. See also: [How to pass Maven settings via environmental vars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31251259/how-to-pass-maven-settings-via-environmental-vars)
The setup the environment variable you can surround the full pipeline in your Jenkinsfile with the withCredentials step. For details see: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/

```
String pipelineVersion = "master"

node {
    deleteDir()
    sh "git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-pipeline.git -b ${pipelineVersion} pipelines"
    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'nexus', usernameVariable: 'NEXUS_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'NEXUS_PASSWORD')]) {
        load './pipelines/s4sdk-pipeline.groovy'
    }
}
```

and a settings.xml like:

```
    <username>${env.NEXUS_USERNAME}</username>
    <password>${env.NEXUS_PASSWORD}</password>
```